# How to hyperlink both post thumnail image and post title text in wordpress?

Tags: permalinks

In the output of following code currently only the post title is getting hyperlinked to the main post but not the image. I want both the image and title to hyperlink to the main post.

```
$string .= '<li>'. get_the_post_thumbnail() .'<a href="'. get_permalink() .'" >'. get_the_title() .'</a><hr/></li>';
```

I tried:

```
$string .= '<li>'<a class="nana" href="'. get_permalink() .'" >. get_the_post_thumbnail() .. get_the_title() .'</a><hr/></li>';
```

but it breaks down the whole site. I'm a beginner. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea when you put the thumbnail between the opening and closing `<a>` tags, but the dot operators and the quotes are wrong, which is why it breaks down the site.

This would be the proper way to write it:

```
$string .= '<li>' .'<a class="nana" href="'. get_permalink() .'" >'. get_the_post_thumbnail() . get_the_title() .'</a><hr/></li>';
```